# How to prove that a Lineal Transformation P2 to R2 is correct? and how to find its Kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

So, this is a question I failed in my last test, im asking here before it shows up again in finals. Could you help me understand how to solve it?

Let P2-> R2 be the transformation defined by T(ax^2+bx+c) =[a+3c , a-c]

a)Show that T is a linear transformation

b)Find the kernel of T

Comment: What if you take two polynomials $p, q$ of degree $2$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ and apply $T$ on $p+q$ and $\alpha p$? Can you then show that $T(p+q)=T(p)+T(q)$ and $T(\alpha p)=\alpha T(p)$? For b) Find $a,b,c$ such that $(a+3c,a-c)=0_{\mathbb{R}}$.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Where are you having difficulties, specifically?

Comment: If it was $\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $T(a,b,c)=(a+3c,a-c)$ could you do it? It's essentially the same.

Comment: @Fakemistake how do i express the solution of the kernel?
Because im not sure if it would be written as Ker(T) = {(0x^2 + x + 0)}

Comment: @K.Jiang Right now im stuck on how to express the answer of the kernel
as i dont know if {(0x^2 + x + 0)} would be written correctly or i have to omit the 0 parts and just put {(x)} as final answer for the kernel